# indigo actionlib client cannot connect to the server

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to make actionlib client/server program on ROS Indigo/Ubuntu 14.04,
but however, I've got a trouble that my actionlib client cannot connect to its server
because the "ActionClient::waitForActionServerToStart()" will be always failed.

And also, this problem occurred in the "actionlib_tutorial" in ROS Indigo
(ros-indigo-actionlib-tutorials).

By tracing the debug messages of ROS console,
I found that the actionlib server tries to make connection
but the client gets no response from status/feedback/result topics.

1. In the "/opt/ros/indigo/include/actionlib/action_client.h",
   the function "ActionClient::statusCb()" was registered but never called at all.
2. so that, in the "actionlib/src/connection_monitor.cpp", the function "ConnectionMonitor::processStatus()" could not notify its condition.
3. then, in the "ConnectionMonitor::waitForActionServerToStart()", the variable "check_connection_condition_" has never success of its "timed_wait()".
4. in the result, ActionClient::waitForActionServerToStar() will be failed.

In ROS Groovy, my program and "actionlib_tutorial" have worked fine.

What should I do?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168426/indigo-actionlib-client-cannot-connect-to-the-server/) by [ST-Lab](https://answers.ros.org/users/18291/st-lab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is actionlib installed? If you are using debs and not on ros-shadow, or your source is old, this is a bug in version 1.11.1  (https://github.com/ros/actionlib/issues/25) that prevented the conneciton monitor to work correctly. This is fixed in 1.11.2

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ST-Lab](https://answers.ros.org/users/18291/st-lab/) on 2014-05-24**:
Hello fergs. Thank you for your answer.

I installed actionlib and other ROS packages by apt-get from public ROS repositry "http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main".

Along your advice, when I checked the version of the actionlib, it shows that.

- ros-indigo-actionlib  1.11.1-0trusty-20140509-0158-+0000
- ros-indigo-actionlib-msgs 1.11.3-0trusty-20140508-2322-+0000

So far, today, the latest version which I can get from publich repositry is "1.11.1".
I'll wait for the new fixed version.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-24**:
Just a note, rather than closing a question, just click the checkmark next to the answer. This will mark the question as answered.

**Comment by [ST-Lab](https://answers.ros.org/users/18291/st-lab/) on 2014-05-26**:
Thank you, fergs.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-26**:
Just a heads up to anyone seeing this, 1.11.2 is now in public indigo according to http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html